# Warning: Use of the "var" keyword is deprecated

Tags: solidity

I am trying to fix the following var warning that the use of var is deprecated. I can't work out what to change it to, any advice would be appreciated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public onlyPayloadSize(3 * 32) returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));

    var _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];



    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    if(transferIns[_from].length > 0) delete transferIns[_from];
    uint64 _now = uint64(now);
    transferIns[_from].push(transferInStruct(uint256(balances[_from]),_now));
    transferIns[_to].push(transferInStruct(uint256(_value),_now));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hey! Just a suggestion instead of linking off-site for code, you should format the code within your post, since stackexchange support its! Also it is very helpful to include the error message that you are getting, along with any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you are getting is because usage of the `var` keyword has been deprecated and explicit types should be used instead.

So providing the key of `allowed` is of type `uint256` you could do the following:

`uint256 _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];`

Or if `allowed` were of type `bytes32`

`bytes32 _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];`

Some reading on the subject:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/control-structures.html#assignment